# How to change color in R geom_raster?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-raster

I am trying to change the color in a heatmap graph. I want the Yellow, Red color scheme instead of the default Blue-Darkblue.

My code

```
a=as.matrix(volcano, ncol=ncol(volcano))
row.names(a)= 1:nrow(a)
library(reshape2)
a1 = melt(a)
colnames(a1) = c('X','Y','value')
head(a1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(a1,aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value),interpolate=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="yellow", high="red", guide="colorbar")
```

I am getting the following output, which I want in a different color scheme. I am not sure on why the last line - `scale_colour_gradient` is not working. All other examples here have this line but with geom_tile function.

[image: Output plot of above code]

Comment: try `scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("yellow","red"))`. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476925/change-colors-of-raster-plot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: just change from `scale_colour_` to scale_fill`

Comment: Thanks guys. Both solutions work

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `fill` in aesthetics, you have to use `scale_fill_gradient` for filling with color. When color is specified in aesthetics, you have to use `scale_color_gradient`.